# How to say that there may exist elements in two sets such that their intersection is not null?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a very basic understanding of set theory. I am trying to put some English sentences into mathematical notations and I am stuck at this one thing.

I have two sets A and B and they **may not be disjoint**, i.e., it may be possible that for some cases, their intersection is null and for some cases, they may have overlapping elements. Consider, for example, two courses which may have unique students or there may be a few students who take up both the courses. If $A=\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}$ denotes the first course and $B=\{b_1, b_2, ..., b_n\}$ denotes the second course, then how do I convey this information mathematically?

Is this notation correct?

$\exists{i \in A,j \in B}$ s.t. $A \cap B \ne \emptyset$

This translates to "there exists some $i$ in $A$ and some $j$ in $B$ for which the intersection of $i$ and $j$ is not null". However, does this also put a constraint that there **must** exist some $i$ and some $j$ for which the intersection is not null? If yes, then what is the right way to denote this information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not correct. It should be simply $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, which does imply that there must exist something they have in common.

Comment: If they may or may not have things in common, then there is really no information to convey.

Comment: I think the wording should depend on what you're trying to say to the reader. For example: Maybe you started with some arbitrary object $X$, and derived from it two sets $A$ and $B$; and depending on the value of $X$, $A$ and $B$ are usually but not always disjoint; and furthermore you're worried that *the reader might assume* that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, which would cause them to overlook some important argument that you're about to make. Is that your situation, or something else...?

Comment: Instead of $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, you could say $\exists x$ s.t. $(x \in A \land x \in B)$, or $\exists i, \exists j$ s.t. $a_i = b_j$ . (The symbol $\land$ is "logical and". I don't know why & is not standard. Also, "such that" is sometimes replaced with | or : .)

Comment: ...or you could say $\exists a \in A, \exists b \in B$ s.t. $a = b$.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Yes, I am worried that the reader might assume that A and B are disjoint. I want to convey that this is not always the case.

Comment: To convey this "non-information", just say what you mean: "$A \cap B = \emptyset$ should not be assumed."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA -- Only sets intersect. Elements of sets do not intersect, unless the elements are also sets.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA -- In this context, the sets are courses, and the elements are students. A student is not a course.

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion in the comments, it sounds like your main purpose is to caution the reader. In that case, you don't need to use terse mathematical symbols. On the contrary, it's probably *better* to use English so that the reader doesn't skim over the warning. So, something like "Note that $A$ and $B$ might not be disjoint" or "Caution: We cannot assume that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint".

Answer (score 0):

I would probably say something along the lines of: "..where $A\cap B \ne \emptyset$ may hold."

Answer (score -2):

The notation is

$$A\cap B\ne \emptyset$$

which means that $A$ and $B$ have at least one element in common (their intersection is not an empty set), or

$$\exists i\in A,B$$

which means there exists (at least) one element which is in $A$ and $B$.

Comment: The statement means: $\exists x (x\in A \wedge x\in B)$.